# Listener in my ViewController to my Custom Cocoapod Class - Swift

Tags: swift, delegates, cocoapods, listener, protocols

I have built my own Cocoapod which currently fires the `updateCounting()` func once a second. My end goal is to use a `protocol` so that I can have a delegate method of sorts in my view controller class that fires everytime `updateCounting()` fires.

My public Cocoapod file currently looks like:

```
public class Service: NSObject {
    var timer = Timer()
    public static let shared = Service()

    public func scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(){
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateCounting), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func updateCounting(){
        NSLog("counting..")
    }
}
```

My VC class currently looks like:

```
import UIKit
import JacquardToolkit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         Service.shared.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval()
    }
}
```

My original thought is to add a protocal to my `Service` class like so:

```
public protocol ServiceDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
    func timerFired()
}

public class Service: NSObject, ServiceDelegate {

    var timer = Timer()
    public static let shared = Service()

    public func scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(){
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.timerFired), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc public func timerFired() {
        NSLog("timerfired")
    }

}
```

So far I have gotten stuck, but I am essentially trying to make a listener in my VC class so that everytime `timerFired()` or `updateCounting()` fires, I can detect that in my VC class and act accordingly. Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You have almost done to implement Delegate pattern, but small corrections you may have to do as like below code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ServiceDelegate {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Service.shared.delegate = self
    Service.shared.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval()
}

func timerFired() {

    NSLog("timerfired")
}
}
public protocol ServiceDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
    func timerFired()
}

public class Service: NSObject {


var timer = Timer()
public static let shared = Service()
weak var delegate:ServiceDelegate?

public func scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(){
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.timerFired), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc public func timerFired() {
    NSLog("timerfired")
    delegate?.timerFired()
}

}
```

Comment: Big help, thank you! I knew I was close, thanks for the quick answer!